# return retrofit raw response as a json object without converting into any specific type of object?

Tags: java, kotlin, retrofit2

I am using Kotlin with retrofit in my project.

I am basically trying to do something very simple.

Having a method, call a retrofit interface that will bring info from another API. Unfortunately, that API responds different types of objects from the same endpoint (depending of the input and results) so, I was able to map response and worked fine.

Now I am trying to avoid mapping to a specific model and instead, just return the raw response and output it on my service as a Json output.

So I made this:

At my service

```
val response = userService.getUser(request).await()
```

UserService:

```
fun getUser(request: User) = client.getInfo(// some parameters )
```

Then at my client (retrofit) I made this:

```
@GET("/api/v1/user/{}")
    fun getInfo( // some paramters

    ): Deferred<ResponseBody>
```

Everytime I use ResponseBody I get an empty result

Everytime I use `Deferred<Response<MySpecificObject>>`

I get a proper Object full with the information. I wanna avoid that at this moment.

My retrofit is configured like this:

```
return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())       .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
            .create()
```

At my dropwizard configuration I added this:

```
bootstrap.objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
        bootstrap.objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

Any idea if that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't know Kotlin and giving an answer in java terms only. I would suggest to make your own http call to your third party and retrieve a raw response from it. Then you can just read the response from `InputStream` even as byte array if you want and do with it anything you want. You will sacrifice development time and development simplicity but gain extreme flexibility. 
However, you don't have to write your own Http request handler. Here are few known third party Http clients:

1. [Apache Http Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/),
2. [OK Http client](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)
3. And my favorite (again disclaimer: written by me) MgntUtils HttpClient: [Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html), [Maven artifacts](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils), [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) with library, sources and javadoc.

MgntUtils Http client may return response as String (`sendHttpRequest()`) or even binary info (`sendHttpRequestForBinaryResponse()`)